# Table Storage query does not populate all fields

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to query a TableStorage with the following method:

```
    public async Task<List<T>> RetrieveEntityAsync<T>(string deviceId) where T : TableEntity, new()
    {
        try
        {
            TableQuery<T> DataTableQuery = new TableQuery<T>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId))
            {
               var filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, deviceId);
               DataTableQuery = new TableQuery<T>().Where(filter);
            }

            var l = new List<T>();
            TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
            do
            {
                var queryResponse = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(DataTableQuery, continuationToken);
                continuationToken = queryResponse.ContinuationToken;
                l.AddRange(queryResponse.Results);
            }
            while (continuationToken != null);
            return l;
        }
        catch (Exception ExceptionObj)
        {
            throw ExceptionObj;
        }
    }
```

invoking it as follows :

```
    List<TelemetryTS> elements = await tabeManager.RetrieveEntityAsync<TelemetryTS>(dto.DeviceIdorId);
```

TelemetryTS is declared as follows:

```
public class TelemetryTS : TableEntity
{

    public TelemetryTS() { }

    public TelemetryTS(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        this.RowKey = rowKey;
    }


    public double AIn { get; set; }
    public double AOut { get; set; }
    public double CosPhi { get; set; }
    public double H { get; set; }
    public string L { get; set; }
    public DateTime MeterTS { get; set; }
    public Int64 PartitionId { get; set; }
    public Int64 Sampling { get; set; }
    public Int64 UTC { get; set; }
    public double VA { get; set; }
    public double VIn { get; set; }
    public double VOut { get; set; }
    public double Var { get; set; }
    public Int64 VarSCnt { get; set; }
    public double Varh { get; set; }
    public double W { get; set; }
    public Int64 WSCnt { get; set; }
    public double Wh { get; set; }
    public double cIn { get; set; }
    public double cOut { get; set; }
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
    public double kVar { get; set; }
    public double kVarH { get; set; }
    public double kW { get; set; }
    public double kWh { get; set; }
    public string mts { get; set; }
    public Int64 nDips { get; set; }
    public Int64 nSwells { get; set; }
    public Int64 tDips { get; set; }
    public Int64 tSlot { get; set; }
    public Int64 tSwells { get; set; }

    public double MaxPotenzaAttiva { get; set; }
    public double MaxTensioneIngresso { get; set; }
    public double MaxPotenzaReattiva { get; set; }
    public double MaxCorrenteIngresso { get; set; }
    public double AvgPotenzaAttiva { get; set; }
    public double AvgTensioneIngresso { get; set; }
    public double AvgPotenzaReattiva { get; set; }
    public double AvgCorrenteIngresso { get; set; }

    public double WhConsumoUltimoGiorno { get; set; }
    public double WhPercRispUltimoGiorno { get; set; }
    public double WhConsumoUltimaSettimana { get; set; }
    public double WhPercRispUltimaSettimana { get; set; }
    public double WhConsumoUltimoMese { get; set; }
    public double WhPercRispUltimoMese { get; set; }

    public double AvgRispDaEfficenzaUltimoGiorno { get; set; }
    public double AvgRispDaEfficienzaUltimaSettimana { get; set; }
    public double AvgRispDaEfficienzaUltimoMese { get; set; }

    public string IoTHubError { get; set; }

    public int severity { get; set; }

}
```

The number of records returned is correct, but in the individual records not all fields are populated as shown in StorageExplorer. For example DateTime fields are not retrieved correctly.

What could be the problem?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What's the meaning of "For example DateTime fields are not retrieved correctly."? Not retrieved or retrieved a incorrect value?

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue.

Comment: Can you please post an answer about how to solve the issue? It may help others.

Comment: @SimoneSpagna, i am also facing same issue, can you please help here to how you resolved the issue. It would really helpful to others.